# Deploying cube generates ddl300 error with FormatString

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, bids, ssas-2008

I modified a fully working Analysis Services cube to change the format of several date fields. Now when I try to deploy it I get the error...

```
The ddl300_300:FormatString element at line 901, column 41 (namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300) cannot appear under Envelope/Body/Execute/Command/Batch/Alter/ObjectDefinition/Database/Dimensions/Dimension/Attributes/Attribute.
```

**Versions**

- Visual Studio 2010 (10.0.40219.1)
- BIDS Helper 2012 (1.6.4.0)
- Deploying to SSAS 2008R2 (10.50.1600.1)

**Details**

In several dimensions I have date attributes that are used as simple display attributes, i.e. not involved in any complex date-time manipulation. Their FormatString property is empty. When I view the cube (e.g. via Excel) the dates appear with both date and time.

I want to show just date, not time. So I changed FormatString to `Short Date` for each of the date attributes. (Also tried `d/MM/yyyy` with the same result.)

As mentioned above, deploying the changes now fails.

**Other discussions**

This issue has been mentioned by others on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/197f9ec4-827a-465c-a8bc-bafcfb874b4d/cube-builds-but-gets-an-error-on-deployment-ddl300300-formatstring-line-element-cannot-appear?forum=sqlanalysisservices) and [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6cbc4ac6-4f94-4aff-9e21-a1abe95e7bbc/deploy-cube-from-visual-studio-2010-to-ssas-2008r2?forum=sqlanalysisservices) but not lead to any resolution apart from backing out the changes to FormatString. It appears that BIDS Helper generates an XML spec that is incorrect for SQL Server 2008R2.

**Request**

If you have seen this before and fixed it please let me know how.

Alternatively, if you are able to use the FormatString property with 2008R2, could you tell me what XML gets generated? If I knew that I could probably edit the XML to bypass the code generated by BIDS Helper.

Comment: Does it help enclosing the format string in quotes? I would try both, single and double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @FrankPl but it does not help. It does not appear to be the content of the FormatString that causes the problem. The error suggests that the structure `<Attribute> ... <ddl300_300:FormatString> ... </ddl300_300:FormatString> ... </Attribute>` is invalid.

Comment: Have you configured the version of the server to deploy to correctly? Right-click on the project node, select Properties/Build, and check the Deployment Server version. This should be 10.0 for Analysis Services 2008, and 10.50 for Analysis Services 2008 R2.

Comment: I have 10.0 selected. The dialog will not allow me to select or type 10.5.

Comment: I expected that setting FormatString back to "Standard" would remove the error and return the behavior to the previous. But this does not work. I have to remove the whole line `<ddl300_300:FormatString>Standard</ddl300_300:FormatString>` by manually editing the relevant *.dim files.

Comment: I would think the problem is the XML namespace prefix `ddl300_300:`, and it could be that it works if you change `<ddl300_300:FormatString>Standard</ddl300_300:FormatString>` to `<FormatString>Standard</FormatString>`

Comment: That's another hopeful suggestion @FrankPl, but no good. The `<FormatString>Short Date</FormatString>` tag is just ignored during the deployment.

Comment: So the format entry seems to be an addition in AS2012 a compared to AS2008. And maybe you should have used BIDSHelper2008, but that does not seem to work with Visual Studio 2010, according to http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/releases/view/121231.

Comment: I'm going to use the more long-winded approach of adding a formatted char field to accompany each date field in the dsv. Then separate KeyColumn from NameColumn in each case. Then the FormatString property becomes irrelevant. I'll post that as an Answer here once I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from comments, no-one has been able to suggest why the FormatString setting does not have the desired effect. It may be a misunderstanding of that property's designed function, or a bug, or a subtle configuration mistake.

I worked around this by implementing a more long-winded approach: added a formatted char field to accompany each date field in the dsv. Then separated KeyColumn from NameColumn in each case. Then the FormatString property becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect myself that installing BIDS helper 2012 creates an incompatibility - SQL 2008 R2 does not understand this attribute, and the fact that there is no error during build, only during deployment to SQL 2008, supports this.

I just ran into this and had to manually remove this line from the dimension source code. Once I had selected a format, I could not get rid of it again.

```
      <ddl300_300:FormatString>Standard</ddl300_300:FormatString>
```

I have not found a workaround - it is necessary to clean up the versions for this error to go away and for the format string to work again. At least, this is what Jeremy suggested as well [in this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/197f9ec4-827a-465c-a8bc-bafcfb874b4d/cube-builds-but-gets-an-error-on-deployment-ddl300300-formatstring-line-element-cannot-appear?forum=sqlanalysisservices).